# Running node.js module (more specifically YUIDoc) in a JVM

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, jvm, ringojs

I want to run the node.js module YUIDoc in a JVM. The reason for this is that YUIDoc is my JavaScript documentation generator of choice, and that I want to be able to run it from a maven-plugin without having to install node.js, npm and such up front.

I have looked at [SprintStack](http://sprintstack.com/) but it seems a bit immature so far.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I have briefly looked at RingoJS. Is there a possibility that NodeJS modules can run on RingoJS?

Comment: I saw this recently... might not work, but you can get Maven to Run Grunt.  Reason I say this is, I uses the grunt plugin to do my JS YUIDoc generation. But I still havn't established if you need Node.js installed on your box, or weather Maven handles all the dependencies in Maven fashion.

http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/